# How to run this SQL statement sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; in Crystal report?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports-2010

This is code does not run in the Crystal Report.

> Error:Failed to retrieve data from the database. Details: ADO Error Code 0x80040e14 Source Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Description: Incorrect syntax near isp_configure. SQL State 42000 Native Error: 102 [Database Vendor Code: 102

[image]

```
  Declare @ReportDate DateTime
Set @ReportDate={?ReportDateR}

Select * from [SBO_SPEL].[dbo].[U_SPEL_SALES_ANALYSIS_TARGET&ACTUAL_UNIT_F] (@ReportDate)

UNION ALL

Select * from [SBO_SPEL].[dbo].[U_SPEL_SALES_ANALYSIS_TARGET&ACTUAL_SE_F] (@ReportDate)
GO


sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 32768;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO


WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00'
GO

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 131072;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal returns to the report the result set from the last SQL statement in a Command or SP. But your last SQL statement has no result set.